# What are the possibilities with Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, system

I want to build a system using drupal and would like your help in asnwering the following questions.

- Is drupal good in build big system where i can custome it as much as i want?
- Can i write any php code i want into drupal?
- Can drupal handle many users visits?

**Can i do the following using drupal:**

- registration for users.
- upload videos.
- give every user a page with power of custome it.
- calculate number if visits in every page.
- write my php code to connect to database and get information from it.

Some people told me that a CMS is not flexible to build all of this and I should start from scratch instead.
Is that true or I can build my system above drupal or other CMS or open source project?

One more thing, do you have examples of such systems built using Drupal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say to all of the above for Drupal, but the same can be said for most CMS systems. If you get the chance to write PHP or some other type of code, that a CMS system is built with, you can do just about anything.

The interesting question is not if this is possible, anything is possible if you have the skills and time to code it. What's interesting is how easy it is. This is, however, quite hard to answer without making it subjective. I prefer Drupal over other CMS/frameworks, a reason is because I believe Drupal is among the very best, but another is also I have invested the time to learn how to do just about anything with Drupal.

I can point out some of the merits using Drupal.

- **It's very flexible.** Drupal uses a hook system, where you can hook into and alter the flow of the code for most things. This means that when certain events happens, you get the possibility to react on it, in your custom code.
- **You can alter the markup of Drupal however you like.** The Drupal theming system can be a bit tricky to learn, but once you master it, you get a very fine grained control over what HTML Drupal produces, making it possible to costumize any Drupal page to your liking.
- **A great community.** There are a lot of people using Drupal. Not only are they using it, but they make their code available through contrib modules on drupal.org. In the Drupal community we have a saying: *There's a module for that*. This is not without reason. A lot of your problems can be solve fully or by a great deal, using free available modules.

There are many more merits to Drupal, but these are the top ones. One of the cons to Drupal, however, is that it's not so easy to learn. This has greatly been improved in Drupal 7 on some areas, but it still isn't easy. But that can be said about most things anyways.